# Rstudio: for-loop of a sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, collatz

I want to find the backtracks sequence in the form of data (as it is from collatz conjecture tibble data from 1 to 10,000) at some point goes above the starting value in that sequence.

This is my output for data frame:

```
structure(list(start = 1:6, seq = list(1L, c(2, 1), c(3, 10, 
5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1), c(4, 2, 1), c(5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1), c(6, 3, 
10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)), length = c(1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9), parity = c("Odd", 
"Even", "Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"), max_val = c(1, 2, 16, 
4, 16, 16)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

This is how i did:

```
has_backtrack <- function(seq) {
  length_seq <- length(seq)
  if (length_seq < 3) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  for (i in 2:(length_seq - 1)) {
    if (seq[i] < seq[1] && seq[i + 1] > seq[i]) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
}
```

However, for my current code it only shows whether a sequence increases but not above the first value.

Backtracks def: is when a sequence reaches a value that is less than the starting integer, but then increases again ABOVE the starting value/integer it can be at least once before reaching one.

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: sample input: 
(i)integer 4, sequence: c(4, 2, 1)
(ii)integer 6, sequence: c(6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)

expected output: integer 6

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the following is what you want. It uses R's vectorized instructions to get all points where the input sequence increases in one instruction, making the code much simpler, without `for` loops.

The function `has_backtrack` returns the indices to the points where the sequence increases, not the sequences values.

The functions `next_collatz` and `collatz` are inspired in [this R-bloggers code](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/testing-the-collatz-conjecture-with-r/).

```r
next_collatz <- function(num) {
  if(num == 1L) {
    invisible(NULL)
  } else if(num %% 2L == 0L) {
    num / 2L
  } else 3L * num + 1L
}
collatz <- function(x) {
  result <- x
  while(x != 1L) {
    x <- next_collatz(x)
    result <- c(result, x)
  }
  result
}

has_backtrack <- function(x) which(diff(x) > 0L)

cltz_6 <- collatz(6)
has_backtrack(cltz_6)
#> [1] 2 4
i <- has_backtrack(cltz_6)
cltz_6[i]
#> [1] 3 5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Another example, with a strictly decreasing input Collatz sequence.

```r
(cltz_16 <- collatz(16))
#> [1] 16  8  4  2  1
(i <- has_backtrack(cltz_16))
#> integer(0)
cltz_16[i]
#> numeric(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

With the data set posted in the question, the Collatz sequences column is a list column and the function `has_backtrack` can be `lapply`ed as follows.
The results show that

- the 1st, 2nd and 4th Collatz sequences are decreasing sequences, there are no indices into increasing points;
- the 3rd and 6th sequences have two points where the sequences increase;
- the 5th sequence has one point only where the sequence increases.

```r
inx_list <- lapply(df1$seq, has_backtrack)
inx_list
#> [[1]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 2 4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And to get the values *before*  the increase point, use `Map`.

```r
Map(\(x, i) x[i], df1$seq, inx_list)
#> [[1]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> numeric(0)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3 5
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> numeric(0)
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 3 5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    start = 1:6, 
    seq = list(1L, c(2, 1), c(3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1), 
               c(4, 2, 1), c(5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1), c(6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)), 
    length = c(1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9), 
    parity = c("Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"), 
    max_val = c(1, 2, 16, 4, 16, 16)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks, this is nice code, however i have a data of collatz conjecture already and it's in tibble form of between integers 1:10,000 so i want to filter the collatz data to create new backtracks data with the def given. sorry, if my question is not clear.

Comment: @user22623213 If your tibble is named `df` and has a column named `collatz` then you can use `has_backtrack(df$collatz)` and then keep only `i[1]`. Does this answer the question and the comments?

Comment: my tibble is collatz_df and has column of start(integers), sequences, parity, length and max_val. so i need to follow your code from the `has_backtrack` ?

Comment: @user22623213 Can you please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(collatz_df))`? I am not understanding how to apply the function in my answer and with actual data it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: okay, will do, thank you sm...

Comment: @user22623213 Done, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `z` as the remainder after the first value. Subset `z` on *id*(`cumsum(z < x[1]) > 1`) and look if `any` of them is `TRUE`.

```
has_backtrack2 <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) < 3) FALSE
  else {
    z <- x[-1]
    any(z[cumsum(z < x[1]) > 1L] > x[1])
  }
}
```

Using `sapply`

```
sapply(df$seq, has_backtrack2)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or for conveniece `Vectorize`d.

```
has_backtrack2v <- Vectorize(has_backtrack2)

has_backtrack2v(df$seq)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Assuming the desired "integer 6" means `which` sequence has backtrack, you can get it accordingly:

```
which(has_backtrack2v(df$seq))
# [1] 6
```

Comment: i did follow your code however, integer 7 has backtracks but the output of your code give false.. i'll try to adjust your code, anw thanks

Comment: @user22623213 specify what you mean by " integer 7"

Comment: okay so, my question is to check what integers has backtracks, 
for integer 7 the sequence is c(7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16 [...]) which the sequence do have multiple backtracks, hence the outcome of integer 7 should be True not False.

Comment: @user22623213 Don't understand, can't see anything "integer 7" in the `structure` you show.

Comment: forgot about the 'integer 7', the solution for my outcome code must be 8,229 rows (between 1:10,000) but using your code i got 7,529 rows...

Comment: @user22623213 I see. Not sure how to help you. Maybe try to make your example better resembling your real data and how exactly you apply the function.